# Magento 2.2.7 Order Email are not working with paypal with status processing

Tags: email, paypal, magento2.2.7, smtp

Magento 2.2.7 Email are not working with paypal with smtp pro. but all others payment order mail are working.

Answer (score 0):

Working internal module confliction....